# pysnmp send timeout when called from django view

Tags: python, django, pysnmp

Im reitryng to get some kids from some network switch and for that im using a purepyton library called pysnmp. its installed w/o problems.

Used a sample code that works.

```
    from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
    cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
    datos = []
    ip = 'theipaddress'
    comunidad_snmp = 'thecomunityv2c'

    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
            cmdgen.CommunityData(comunidad_snmp),
            cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
            '.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0', # sysDescr.0
            lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True
    )

    if errorIndication:
             print(errorIndication)
    elif errorStatus:
            print(errorStatus)
    else:
            for name, val in varBinds:
                    datos.append({'nombre': name.prettyPrint(), 'valor': val.prettyPrint()})

    print datos
```

our problem is that if I copy this code(as is) inside any view the result its always

```
"No SNMP response received before timeout"
```

is there something we need to add for this to work as expected?.

the environment is cents 6

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your SNMP/UDP queries from Django host get filtered while your command-line tests do not?

Digging deeper: your code invokes pysnmp with default, asyncore-based transport. If Django (or some of its components) somehow uses asyncore in a non-cooperative way, pysnmp/django systems may somehow interfere... A way to avoid such interference  would be  use your own map of pysnmp I/O socket objects like this:

```
...
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dispatch import AsynsockDispatcher

cmdGen.snmpEngine.registerTransportDispatcher(AsynsockDispatcher())

mySockMap = {}
cmdGen.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.setSocketMap(mySockMap)
...
```

Another idea is to enable pysnmp debugging to see what's going on there:

```
import sys
from pysnmp import debug 
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all', printer=sys.stderr.write))
```

There are other, less verbose pysnmp debugging flags (see pysnmp.debug).